# Запуск скрита из скрипта

Tags: python

Подскажите, как лучше сделать. У меня скрипт на Python в ходе выполнения запускает другой скрипт на Perl, а тот в свою очередь должен требовать ввода пользователем пути к файлу в ручную (не как параметр к запуску). Вопрос. Как заставить Python перехватывать этот путь и автоматически его заполнять без ввода пользователем? Переписывать Perl, чтоб он принимал путь как параметр через @ARGV мне если честно в лом и не охота, итак все работает нормально....

Answer (score 3):

[Pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/)

> Pexpect is a pure Python Expect. It allows easy control of other applications.
>
> Pexpect is a pure Python expect-like module. Pexpect makes Python a better tool for controlling other applications.
>
> Pexpect is a pure Python module for spawning child applications; controlling them; and responding to expected patterns in their output. Pexpect works like Don Libes' Expect. Pexpect allows your script to spawn a child application and control it as if a human were typing commands.

Comment: Гм.... Спасибо за уделенное внимание, но можно то же самое тока на общероссийском гражданском, а не на общепрограмистском-международном......

Comment: Нагуглил, стало получаться. Но в процессе выскакивает ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "argv.py", line 23, in <module>
    get.interact ()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1492, in interact
    self.__interact_copy(escape_character, input_filter, output_filter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1520, in __interact_copy
    data = self.__interact_read(self.child_fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1510, in __interact_read
    return os.read(fd, 1000)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

И все падае

Comment: Большое спасибо всем, особенно Ilya Pirogov, за ответ. Кое что нагуглив и толком ничего не поняв из переводчика англо-гугла, методом тыка все заработало. Если будет не сложно, подкиньте толковую русскоязычную книжицу-справочник по модулям Питона. Буду премного благодарен. А то с моим англицким....

Comment: @Asid, есть хорошая книжка English grammar in use. 

Без определенного уровня чтения на английском далеко не уедешь. Так что на данный момент приоритет - английский язык.

Comment: @Asid, "Дэвид Бизли - Python. Подробный справочник" - по идее это именно то что вам нужно

Comment: Кстати, за что англам такая почесть? Почему именно английский считается основным и приоритетным международным? А не к примеру, эсперанто))) Дискриминация......